# Очистка файла через некоторое время

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы

У меня записываются некие данные в файлe, но их нужно удалить через 5 минут из этого файла. Как можно это сделать?

Answer (score 2):

Все происходит на вашем компьютере? Тогда пишете скрипт, который засыпает на 5 минут, а после просыпания -  делает то, что нужно с вашим файлом, например удаляет или очищает его.

Comment: Засыпание можно реализовать через модуль time функцию sleep.